# How to enable billing for an existing Places API Key?

Tags: google-places-api

I have been using two Places API Keys (one for Android and the other for iOS) and would like to enable billing for them. But I cant find a way to include them in my Cloud console -> API Dashboard. Do I have to get new keys from the dashboard and replace the old ones? Or is there any way to include the existing Keys?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Billing support is free of charge in Google: https://cloud.google.com/support/ or https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Comment: I tried them and they told me I need a Map API technical support, and that require a premium plan subscription which I don't have.

Comment: In this case try to follow this documentation to enable billing in your project: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage#enable-billing

Comment: Thank you xomena.
I understand I can enable API (which then generate a new API Key) in a project then enable billing for the project. But that means I need to use the new key. I wonder if there is any way I can use existing key, i.e. add the key into a project.

Comment: No, you cannot pass an API key from one project to another one.

Comment: Thank you very much xomena!
At least I know I will just have to generate new keys and replace keys in the code. This does make sense for security concern.